# Am I able to run OS X 10.11 on my Mac or not?

Tags: macos

I have a Mac. It is running Mac OS X 10.6.8. It is ten years old, came out in 2006.  I go to the App Store.  The listing for OS X 10.11 claims it is "compatible with 10.6.8", but when I "get" (click on the Get button) the update, it comes up with a message that says "...cannot be installed on this computer."

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: I know of no Apple computer produced in 2006 that officially supports anything later then Mac OS X 10.7.5 and some made in 2006 officially supports only Mac OS X 10.6.8.

Answer (score 1):

Checking [everymac](http://www.everymac.com/systems/by_year/macs-released-in-2006.html) none of the Macs listed is eligible to run 10.11 El Capitan.

The latest supported system for Xeon/Core 2 Duo processor equipped Macs from the year 2006 is 10.7.5 and 10.6.8 for Core Duo.

Being "compatible with 10.6.8" means that any Mac running 10.6.8 **and** supporting 10.11 can be upgraded directly. Macs supporting El Capitan either contain Core 2 Duo (2007-2010), i3/5/7 or Xeon (2008-) processors.